# In Flutter BLoC state management, can you pass an event as a state parameter?

Tags: flutter, bloc, clean-architecture

In Flutter BLoC state management, can you pass an event as a state parameter? Is it allowed? Could it be slow? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Or maybe there is a better implementation? Thank you.

MORE INFO:
When creating a BLoC with Freezed you get the when, whenOrNull, maybeWhen and other functional methods to easily direct the flow of your states. It can be equivalent to a if conditional statement.

My use case on why I want to pass the event as a parameter to the **success** state is I have multiple sign up stages and I want the BLoC to only have 4 states namely, idle, loading, success and error and I want the Sign Up stages to be handled by only one BLoC which is the SignUpBloc.

So whenever I click the CREATE PROFILE button from SignUpProfileView and trigger signUpProfile event, the success state will know that the emit success came from the signUpProfile event and I can handle the code from there like navigating to the next sign up stage next to profile sign up. Hope that makes sense. But yeah, that's my question or are there better ways to do it? Do I really need to create a separate BLoC for each sign up stage? Thank you for any answers that could clarify this as I am not so sure. Cheers!

Please refer to the code below:

```
BlocConsumer<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      state.whenOrNull(
        success: (event) {
          event.whenOrNull(
            signUpProfile: (profile) {
              // handle success for profile sign up completion like navigating to the next sign up stage
            },
            signUpAddress: (address) {
              // handle success for address sign up completion like navigating to the next sign up stage
            },
            signUpPayment: (payment) {
              // handle success for payment sign up completion like navigating to the next sign up stage
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
```

Comment: just use changenotifier at this point. you could have multiple states at a time in 1 one class.those are currentStage (enum is good here), properties for user datas, and async operation states (idle, loading, error, success)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would like to explore on using BLoC at the moment and just try to what extent I can make a clean code with it. So just curious if there are anyone who has this use case before as well. I could easily just create on BLoC for each sign up stage but I want to know if this is also possible. Thanks @Qori